# Cómo evitar repetir registro al guardar en MySQL

Tags: android, mysql

Buenas. Tengo un problemilla y no sé cómo solucionarlo.

Cuando le doy a guardar el registro no sé cómo comprobar antes de que lo guarde si dicho registro está ya en la BBDD y que lance un mensaje al usuario de que el registro está repetido.

En la base de datos tengo una id que es campo clave y es autonúmerico.

Os dejo mi código por si os sirve de algo.

```
   private void insertToDatabase(String nombre, String imagen, String usuario){
    class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String nombre = nombrenuevo.getText().toString();
            String usuario = UsuarioNuevoSuper;
            String imagen = ImagenNuevoSuper;


            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://XXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXX.PHP");

            try {

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nombre", nombre));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("usuario", usuario));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("imagen", imagen));

                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                client.execute(post);


            } catch (IOException e) {

                ToastPersonalizado miToast = new ToastPersonalizado(getApplicationContext(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                miToast.show("Fallo al insertar el supermercado");
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Anadir_Productos_Principal.class);
                in.putExtra("usuario", UsuarioNuevoSuper);
                startActivity(in);
                finish();                }

            return "success";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            Introducida();
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Anadir_Productos_Principal.class);
            in.putExtra("usuario", UsuarioNuevoSuper);
            startActivity(in);
            finish();
        }
    }

    SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
    sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(nombre, imagen, usuario);
}
```

Espero que me podáis ayudar. Si necesitáis alguna información más por favor decidmelo.

Muchas gracias por vuestros comentarios. Os dejo también el código del PHP que hace la función de inserción en la BBDD, por si me podéis dar vuestra opinión de como implementar vuestros comentarios.

```html
<?PHP
// Incluye la clase a la conexion a la DB
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// Conectar a DB
$db = new DB_CONNECT();


$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
$imagen=utf8_encode($_POST['imagen']);
$usuario=$_POST['usuario'];


$query_search = "insert into supermercados(nombre,imagen,usuario) values ('".$nombre."','".$imagen."','".$usuario."')";
$query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: Usa un primary key

Comment: El primary key lo tengo en el id

Comment: Entonces puedes añadir indices únicos a aquellos campos que forman tu registro irrepetible

Comment: Pero viendo bien tu pregunta, la validación debe hacerse del lado del servidor, justo antes de invocar tu insert debes validar que el registro no existe, si creas los indices no será una manera elegante, ya que te darías cuenta cuando has caído en el error, deberás crear un método (con jdbc o jpa no se que estes usando) para que busque si tu registro está repetido en base a aquellos campos que necesitas que sean únicos. Dependiendo del resultado, devolverás una respuesta a tu app.

Comment: Desde android solo envías los datos a registrar, eso de la validación y todo eso va en el servidor, hay que recordar eso.

Comment: Ósea que primero tengo que traer a la app los datos de la BBDD y compararlos con los datos que voy a introducir?

Comment: @user3737118 Si quieres evitar repetir registro al guardar en MySQL la validación debe ser en la base de datos. Evita extraer datos para compararlos y después validar. Te sugiero agregar mejor que ejecuta tu archivo .php y ahí se puede realizar la validación.

Answer (score 1):

La validación la tendría que realizar el Stored Procedure (seguramente esto se usa) que ejecuta tu .php.

**Si deseas evitar repetir registro al guardar en MySQL la validación debe ser en la base de datos. Evita extraer datos para compararlos y después validar.**

Una forma de tener retroalimentación para saber si realizando el [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3291438/250260) tu sepas si se inserto o no el registro, entonces tu puedes definir como respuesta del [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3291438/250260) que valor recibes, esto para determinar si ya existe el registro.

Este sería un ejemplo de como procesarías la respuesta:

```
    if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        String line;
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
            response+=line;
        }
    }
    else {
        response="";    

    }
```

En response podrías definir entregar por ejemplo un "si" o un "no", o puede ser un valor numérico, esto para que el cliente sepa que el registro ya existe.

Te recomiendo dejar de usar las clases de Apache ya que Android las considera obsoletas, usa [HttpUrlConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).

Answer (score 0):

Como te han comentado estas validaciones son preferibles en el lado del servidor dentro del mismo metodo de insertar, ya que si haces varias llamadas a tu servidor caes en una mala practica porque consumes más datos del dispositivo y por lo tanto más bateria.

Dentro de tu archivo de PHP en el lado del servidor debes verificar si existe el registro, esto lo puedes hacer con un

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabla WHERE condiciones;
```

si te retorna un 0 significa que no tienes ningun registro con esos datos, si es asi procedes con tu instruccion INSERT, caso contrario retornas un mensaje a tu app puede ser un código de error o directamente el mensaje de la validación a traves de un JSON, este lo lees en tu aplicación y en base al código de error o exito muestras la información que necesites.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es agregar un CONSTRAINT de **unicidad** al campo *usuario* para evitar que la base guarde registros repetidos.

Y del lado de tu servicio en PHP manejar la excepción y devolver el mensaje de error. O incluso antes de guardarlo, checar si existe comparando el usuario que acabas de recibir.

1. "Cachas" el usuario capturado con tu servicio de php.
2. Ves si hay uno igual en la base. (algo como `SELECT FROM USUARIOS WHERE USUARIO = $usuarioCapturado` por ejemplo)
3. Si ya existe un usuario así, respondes el POST con un mensaje de error.
4. Si no, simplemente lo guardas.

Espero te ayude, suerte!.